# Google Maps add new Marker and delete old Marker with one mouse click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to embed Google Maps into a JavaFX WebView. I have one Marker in a `markers[]`-Array that is displayed at the beginning of my program.

When I click on the map a new marker appears. So I have two.

If I click on a button, which invokes the method `deleteOldMarkers()` the first marker is deleted. So far so good.

**What I'm trying to do is to delete the old marker together with creating a new one without clicking on the button all the time.**

But if I invoke the function `deleteOldMarker()` together with the  `addNewMarkers()`-function it only adds markers but doesn't delete the old ones.

My FXML-project looks like this:

FXMLDocument.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="578.0" prefWidth="905.0"    
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com 
/fxml/1" fx:controller="googlemapstestproject.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <WebView fx:id="view" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="16.0"    
prefHeight="553.0" prefWidth="848.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

GoogleMapsTestProject.java:

```
public class GoogleMapsTestProject extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root =  
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

FXMLDocumentController.java:

```
@FXML
private WebView view;
@FXML
private WebEngine webEngine;
final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("Map.html");

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    webEngine = view.getEngine();
    webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toString());
    }
```

}

and finally Map.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=  
    AIzaSyAOzn0IHzu49M3kuocoMdcDC_BPMUVNA84&signed_in=true"></script>
        <style>#mapcanvas { height: 100%; width: 100%}</style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
        <div id="mapcanvas">
            <script type="text/javascript">

                var markers = [];

                document.map = new 
google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"));
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.8, 9.2);
                var Options = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    zoomControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                };
                var map = new  
google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), Options);

                map.addListener('click', function (event) {
                    deleteMarker();
                    addNewMarkers(event.latLng)
                });


                var map;
                var markers = [];

                // Adds a new marker at the current mouse position when 
                   clicked
                map.addListener('click', function (event) {
                    deleteMarker();
                    addNewMarkers(event.latLng);
                });

                // Adds a marker to the map and pushes it into markers 
                   array
                function addNewMarkers(location) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
                        map: map,
                        icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons
                               /yellow-dot.png",
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);
                }

                function deleteMarker() {
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        markers[i].setMap(null);
                    }
                    markers = [];
                }
                ;

            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: deleteMarker() should get called after addNewMarkers()

Comment: but if I wright deleteMarker() after addNewMarkers(event.latLng), the old markers are still not deleted, it just keeps creating new ones

Comment: have you checked your marker array length and also if is it global or not

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip, I added the whole project code, it should be runnable by copy and paste now.

Answer (score 1):

1. change `deleteMarker` to delete *all* the markers (you don't want the first marker left around, you want the last marker left, if you have already added it to the array)
2. call `deleteMarker` before you call `addNewMarkers`
3. You don't need `deleteOldMarkers`

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gw8LLzhL/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    deleteMarker();
    addNewMarkers(event.latLng)
  });
}
var map;
var markers = [];
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

// Adds a marker to the map and pushes it into markers array
function addNewMarkers(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png",
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}

function deleteMarker() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Im getting crazy, I can see that your code works perfectly, and I don't see any difference to mine. But it's not working with my code. I did as you suggested. The deleteMarker()-function deletes all markes. But it only works as long as I don't put the function in front of the addNewMarkers()-function. If I put the deleteMarker()-function infront of the addNewMarkers(location, map)-function in the addListener the old markers stay. Even if I invoke the deleteOldMarkers-method by clicking a "delete" button, only the last marker is deleted, all the others stay

Comment: ok now I see the problem. The markers are deleted, but they only get "deleted" when I zoom in/out. Why is it automatically refreshed in your example @geocodezip?

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is that I'm displaying it in a JavaFX WebView which isn't reloaded when it should be?

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about JavaFx WebView.

Comment: yeah, apologies for that, I edited my original post.